# Adding additional information to user accounts in Trac

Tags: plugins, trac

For my Trac plugin, I would like to add a color (as string or rgb values) to each user for use from somewhere else in the plugin. The color should be configurable via the admin page.

Is it possible to add another column to the table in the Users settings of the AccountManagerPlugin panel, and if it is, how do I add the information to the database so I can access it from elsewhere?

Another option would be to make a new Admin Panel for my plugin, which is what I am currently doing, with a table with just the user names and their colors. But in this case, although I already have the empty admin panel, I don't know how to add the table and add new items to the database.

To explain what I need the colors for: 
My plugin adds a new export option for tickets, and formats them with my own html and css structure. The tickets contain the owner's name, and this name should be displayed with their respective colors. The code for this already exists, now I just need to retrieve the colors from the database, and beforehand save them to the database via the admin panel.

The colors should be changable only via the admin page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Users admin panel in Trac, however the [AccountManagerPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin) has a User management panel. Let me know if you are using the AccountManagerPlugin and I'll provide more info on that.

Keeping the discussion within the scope of Trac, you could implement the ability for the user to make a selection through a preference panel by implementing [IPreferencePanelProvider](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.prefs.api.IPreferencePanelProvider). You could save the value in the [session_attribute](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DatabaseSchema#DatabaseSchemaTrac0.12) table and make use of it anywhere else. For an attribute named `user_color`, the value can be retrieved using `req.session.get('user_color')`.

Examples can be found in [trac.prefs.web_ui](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.1.6/trac/prefs/web_ui.py). I've linked to the code in Trac 1.1.6 because the module was refactored so that the preferences were more modular [#9162](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/9162).

Comment: Yes, the user management panel of the AccountManagerPlugin is what I mean. I will edit the question to be more specific and will also try to describe what I want to do more in detail.

Comment: The colors should be managed only by the admin, so I can not use the IPreferencePanelProvider. Also, the colors should be consistent over multiple sessions and accessible by all users (even non logged in), so I think the only option is using the database. The color should be a setting that belongs to the user permanently (changeable by the admin in rare cases, but usually set once and then permanent.)

Comment: The statements I made about storing data in the `session_attribute` table still apply. If you want to append to the AccountManagerPlugin's user table, you'll need to implement [ITemplateStreamFilter](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.web.api.ITemplateStreamFilter) and modify the template using Genshi stream functions. Alternatively you could modify the table using JavaScript.